# enviar imagen con append jquery en dropzone

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, dropzone.js

Estoy tratando de enviar un archivo de foto y otros datos de texto, a parte del input de multiples fotos de dropzone.

```
var myDropzone1 = new Dropzone("div#image-upload", { 
            url: "publicar/store",
            //paramName: "profile",
            autoProcessQueue:false,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            maxFilesize:1,
            maxFiles:5,
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            init: function(){
                //


                myDropzone1 = this; // closure
                var btn1 = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
                btn1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();


                });

                this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, data) {
                        var ofrecido = $('input:radio[name=ofrecido]:checked').val();
                        var titulo = $("#titulo").val();
                        var descripcion = $("#descripcion").val();
                        var precio = $("#precio").val();
                        var moneda = $('input:radio[name=moneda]:checked').val();
                        var telefono = $("#telefono").val();
                        var email = $("#email").val();
                        var departamento = $('#departamento').val();
                        var ciudad = $('#ciudad').val();



                        data.append("principal",$('#principal')[0].files[0]);

                        //data.append("archivo",$('#archivo')[0].files[0]);

                        data.append("ofrecido", ofrecido);
                        data.append("titulo", titulo);
                        data.append("descripcion", descripcion);
                        data.append("precio", precio);
                        data.append("moneda", moneda);
                        data.append("telefono", telefono);
                        data.append("email", email);
                        data.append("departamento", departamento);
                        data.append("ciudad", ciudad);

                });
                this.on("success", function(file, xhr){

                     alert(file.xhr.response);
                    $("#anuncioMsg").fadeOut("slow");
                    $('#publicadoMsg').fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#form2").fadeOut("slow");

                    $('#completoMsg').css("display", "block");
                })

            }


  });
```

Cuando envio me aparece que el Form Data de la siguiente manera

```
principal: (binary)
```

Siendo que deberia ser:

```
file[0]: (binary)
```

Como podria enviar otro archivo de foto con dropzone a parte del input de imagenes propio? (estoy utilizando Laravel para el back-end)

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi es mas eficiente y es lo que necesitas
recuerda colocar el tag `multiple` y el name como `arreglo`

```
var myDropzone1 = new Dropzone("div#image-upload", { 
            url: "publicar/store",
            //paramName: "profile",
            autoProcessQueue:false,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            maxFilesize:1,
            maxFiles:5,
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            init: function(){
                //
                myDropzone1 = this; // closure
                var btn1 = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
                btn1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });

                this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, data) {
                    // nota no veo donde este tu var data = new formData();
                    // serializa todos los elementos contenidos en el form con id form! si son 100 imagenes las serializa todas
                    // las agrega a formData incluyendo input text, textarea ..etc todo lo contenido en el form y lo envia!
                    var data = new formData(document.getElementById("#form"));

                });
                this.on("success", function(file, xhr){

                     alert(file.xhr.response);
                    $("#anuncioMsg").fadeOut("slow");
                    $('#publicadoMsg').fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#form2").fadeOut("slow");

                    $('#completoMsg').css("display", "block");
                })

            }
  });
```

Comment: el data es el parametro de la funcion.. voy  a probar la forma que dices